# Is there any way to export a variable from an React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Is there a way I can export a variable from a React component to use it in my custom hook?

The code looks like this:-

```
function App()
{
    const SignIn=()=>{
        //Some code here

        var userId = data.info.username;
        //Some code here
    }
    return(
        <div className='App'>
        ....
        </div>
    )
}
```

I need to use the userId in some other file. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Where does the 'data' come from? Result of an API call?

Comment: please put that in redux.

Comment: The data comes from an API call

Comment: So you must perform the API call at higher level, or call an setter function (received by a props) to update global storage.
React state or whatever state management library is OK for this.

In React you must not work in the way you are designing the code above: a local property of a component stay inside the component, or it is passed through childrens.

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.setItem('userId',data.info.username);
```

and to get the data

```
const userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");
```

also read about redux and redux-persist
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux

Comment: The author is asking for something like sharing data in two different components and he's probably doing it wrong. Suggesting the usage of localStorage here is an anti-pattern.

Comment: so what if you refresh the page on other parts of the website and you lose the login information? When we are talking about login information like userId or JWT token you need to store it somewhere. LocalStorage or in a HTTP-only Cookies even though quite unsecure is not anti-pattern and good for testing an afterwards switch to a more secure variant. An ephemeral solution will be lost at every refresh and will make working in the frontend a nightmare.

Comment: The author is not talking of keeping the state persistent on page reload, is not talking about JWT token or anything similar. He asked "how to pass data from a component to another" and your asnwer seems to suggest "use localStorage"... which is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

you can use createcontext()-[React.createContext()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)

```
userDetails.js
  
import React from "react";

const UserDetails = React.createContext({ user: null });

export default UserDetails ;
```

in App.js

```
import UserDetails from "./userDetails"
function App()
{
    const SignIn=()=>{
        //Some code here

        var userId = data.info.username;
        //Some code here
    }
    return(
       <UserDetails.provider value={{user:userId}}>
        <div className='App'>
        ....
        </div>
        </UserDetails.provider>
    )
}
```

in child or need component

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import UserDetails from "./userDetails"
  const userIdFetch = useContext(UserDetails);
  console.log(userIdFetch.user) //u will get user id
```